# Can you change the XML Declaration of a WCF Client Request? If so, how?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I am writing a library to consume a 3rd Party Web Service (which I obviously cannot change). The library is currently set to .Net Standard 2.0 so that I can use it in my current application (.Net Framework 4.6.2) and in future projects which will likely be developed in .Net Core. This is not a requirement, but I'd like to keep it this way if possible.

I used the Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider utility to generate the proxy classes from the WSDL. So my basic client factory looks like the following:

```
public static class AuthenticationClientFactory
{
    public static AuthenticationClient CreateNew()
    {
        //Specify the binding to be used for the client.
        BasicHttpsBinding binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();

        //Specify the address to be used for the client.
        EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(Globals.WebServiceAuthenticationURL);

        var client = new AuthenticationClient(binding, address);

        return client;
    }
}
```

When calling the "AuthenticateAsync" method on the generated AuthenticationClient above, the request is created like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:MessageId i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:h="http://centiro.com/facade/shared/1/0/datacontract" />
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <AuthenticateRequest xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Centiro.Facade.Common.Operations.Authenticate" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://centiro.com/facade/shared/1/0/servicecontract">
      <d3p1:Password>Pass123</d3p1:Password>
      <d3p1:UserName>User123</d3p1:UserName>
    </AuthenticateRequest>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Using SoapUI, I tested the XML against the service and I received a "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request". At first I stripped everything from the soap message down, and finally narrowed the problem down to the XML Declaration. Stripping the XML Declaration completely, or changing the declaration to "" allows the service to successfully process the request.

So the question is, how do I either completely strip the XML Declaration, or even better change the declaration to say "utf-8" instead (which I confirmed works through SoapUI)?

Things I've already tried:

- Explicitly changing the TextEncoding on the BasicHttpsBinding to utf-8. XML declaration still says utf-16.
- Creating a CustomBinding with the TextMessageEncodingBindingElement explicitly set to Soap11, and utf-8 encoding.
- Using a MessageInspector to re-encode the Message using utf-8. (But this ends up only re-encoding the BODY of the message)

This seems like it should be such a simple change. At this point, I'm ready to build my own client through a WebClient object so I have better control, and I'll just build the objects and serialization myself. I've read in multiple places that WCF automatically encodes everything in utf-8 by default, so I'm not sure why the declaration states "utf-16" to begin with.

Comment: the only way I found of doing it is to parse a string like Yitzhak solution.  The parse must contain at least the ident line and the root tag.

Comment: Is there an `Authenticate` as well as an `AuthenticateAsync`?  If so, what happens if you call that instead?

Comment: @dbc Unfortunately the Authenticate and AuthenticateAsync methods both produce exactly the same Soap Message.

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily, the configuration of the binding has set up the Text encoding. 
Please try to use the below way.

```
  IService service = factory.CreateChannel();
            using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel)service))
            {
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
                service.GetData();
            }
```

If we use the proxy class.

```
  ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
            using (OperationContextScope ocs=new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
```

Besides, please use the client proxy class to call the service, it should already encapsulate the text encoding.
I ever encountered this similar issue, but I do not know if the solution solved the problem. Wish it is useful to you.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: I had to set the executable to target .Net Framework in order to gain access to WebOperationContext. Once I did that, the XML Declaration suddenly disappeared, but once I targeted .Net Core again, the declaration came back. Unfortunately, because the declaration is no longer written targeting .Net Framework I can't validate if this works.

Comment: Which security mode do you use on your server? Core does not support transportwithmessagecredentail securiy mode. it is not well compatible with WCF.
In addition, can you capture this https request through fiddler (we need to configure the winhttp proxy)? 
This helps us view the contents of the specific request.

Answer (score -1):

> c#

```
void Main()
{
    XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-16'?>
                    <root>
                        <row>some text</row>
                    </root>");
    Console.WriteLine(xml.Declaration);

    XDocument doc = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
        new XElement(xml.Root)
    );

    Console.WriteLine(doc.Declaration);
    Console.WriteLine(doc);
}
```

Comment: LINQ to XML makes it easy.

Comment: This works to change the declaration of an XML message, but the difficulty is changing the declaration of a WCF System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message. Unfortunately I don't believe it's as simple as  setting an XML string as the actual message. If it is, then I apparently have no idea where to do it.